# Logarithmic equation $\log_2(x+4)=\log_{4x+16}8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, logarithms, quadratics, substitution

So the problem goes:

> What is the product of all solutions in the equation
>   $$\log_2(x+4)=\log_{4x+16}8$$

The solution to this should be $31\over4$, but  I got $-14$. This is what I did:

\begin{align*}
\log_2(x+4) & = \log_{4x+16}8\\
\log_2(x+4) & = \frac{1}{\log_8(4x+16)}\\
\log_2(x+4) & = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{3}\log_2 4(x+4)}\\
\log_2(x+4) & = \frac{3}{\log_2 4+ \log_2(x+4)}\\
\log_2(x+4) & = \frac{3}{2 + \log_2(x+4)}\\
(\log_2(x+4))^2+2\log_2(x+4)-3 & =0\\
t^2+2t-3 & = 0 && \text{let $t = \log_2 (x + 4)$}
\end{align*} 
Then $t_1=3,\ t_2=-1$.  And from here, I get $x_1=4,\ x_2=-{7\over2}$

$x_1 \cdot x_2=-14$

I'm not sure where I messed up, or if there is a solution I didn't find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be $t_1=1$ and $t_2=-3$ and the rest is true.

I got $x=-2$ or $x=-\frac{31}{8}.$

Comment: Wow, I messed up in the quadratic formula, by doing b instead of -b, didn't expect that small of an error. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: You are welcome @Aleksa